# Verifying Facebook account in order to create an application

Tags: facebook, credit-card, verification

It asks me to verify my credit cart. How much $s I have to load to my credit cart from my bank account for that?

(Note: When I'm going to shop on internet, and lets say there is something for 3.90$ I load 4$ to my credit cart then I proceed to shopping. There lefts 0.10$ and I'm reloading 0.10$ from my credit to my bank account so that no one will be able to get that 0.10$ even if they know my credit cart information, coz you know it is emty now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook will not charge your credit card if you add it to your account..
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/386/

Answer (score 0):

ok this is what you should basically be having in your account

1. atleast 10 friends.
2. a verified phone number.
3. atleast 5 photos.
4. Some posts.
5. fill in basic information ie.location ,hometown.

just the basics.If still stuck submit a ticket to facebook developer team am sure they will be of help